# Polymorphic factory

Tags: c++, design-patterns, abstract-factory

Consider the following code:

```
template <typename T>
class DrawerFactory
{
protected:
    DrawerFactory() {};
private:
    virtual shared_ptr<IDrawer> GetDrawer(T settings) = 0;
};

class ConcreteDrawerFactoryA : public DrawerFactory<SettingsA>
{
public:
    shared_ptr<IDrawer> GetDrawer(SettingsA settingsA) override
    {
        if (settingsA.style == A) return make_shared<ConcreteDrawerA>(settingsA.length, settingsA.stroke, settingsA.opacity);
        else return make_shared<ConcreteDrawerB>(20, .5);
    };
};

class ConcreteDrawerFactoryB : public DrawerFactory<SettingsB>
{
public:
    shared_ptr<IDrawer> GetDrawer(SettingsB settingsB) override
    {
        if (settingsB.type == TYPEC) return make_shared<ConcreteDrawerC>(settingsB.width, settingsB.height);
        else return make_shared<ConcreteDrawerD>(10, 2);
    };
};
```

I can get a drawer by:

```
ConcreteDrawerFactoryA().GetDrawer(settingsa);
```

or

```
ConcreteDrawerFactoryB().GetDrawer(settingsb);
```

What I'd like to do is:

```
DrawerFactory().GetDrawer(settingsa);
DrawerFactory().GetDrawer(settingsb);
```

Is there a way to set this up without having to continually add overloads to `DrawerFactory` for each concrete factory I want to add?

Comment: The only way would be to cast `Settings` inside `GetDrawer`. A more OO solution would be to make `Settings` deal with "generic" name-value pairs, such as `settings.getInt("width")`

Comment: `DrawerFactory()` makes no sense as DrawerFactory has a pure virtual method...

Comment: jpo38: I know it won't work the way I want as written, hence the question

Comment: Don't make `DrawerFactory` a template and don't make `GetDrawer` virtual. Provide several overloads of `GetDrawer`, one for each Settings type. There is no indication in your problem statement that the factory itself needs to be polymorphic.

Comment: @arkadiy you're suggesting that using a string that cannot be compiletime checked would be "more OO"?

Comment: @ROX Use enums if you prefer. And, casts cannot be compile-time checked either. In any case, let's think what an abstract factory with "settings" does. It takes some free form information, such as XML or a record set, and constructs an implementation of some interface out of that. Along the line, we have to convert free-form data to structured data. We have abstraction for structured data: the interface.  Name/value pair based config allows us to have an abstraction for free-form data. Hence, more OO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of factory hierarchy and virtual dispatch you could make use of templates and specialization:

```
#include <memory>

struct IDrawer { };
struct Drawer1: IDrawer { };
struct Drawer2: IDrawer { };
struct Drawer3: IDrawer { };
struct Drawer4: IDrawer { };

template <class T>
struct DrawerGetterImpl;

struct DrawerFactory {
    template <class T>
    std::shared_ptr<IDrawer> GetDrawer(T settings) {
        return DrawerGetterImpl<T>::GetDrawer(settings);
    }
};

struct SettingsA { int style; };

template <>
struct DrawerGetterImpl<SettingsA> {
    static std::shared_ptr<IDrawer> GetDrawer(SettingsA settings) {
        if (settings.style == 1) {
            return std::make_shared<Drawer1>();
        }
        return std::make_shared<Drawer2>();
    }
};

struct SettingsB { int type; };

template <>
struct DrawerGetterImpl<SettingsB> {
    static std::shared_ptr<IDrawer> GetDrawer(SettingsB settings) {
        if (settings.type == 1) {
            return std::make_shared<Drawer3>();
        }
        return std::make_shared<Drawer4>();
    }
};

int main() {
    DrawerFactory().GetDrawer(SettingsA{1});
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/qfxsJxI2JeacPSTS)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, your factory seemed to have no state, so can you achieve what you want without a polymorphic factory? For example something like this...

```
template<class T>
std::shared_ptr<IDrawer> MakeDrawer(T settings);

template<>
std::shared_ptr<IDrawer> MakeDrawer<SettingsA>(SettingsA settings)
{
    return std::make_shared<ConcreteDrawerA>(); // use settings really
}

template<>
std::shared_ptr<IDrawer> MakeDrawer<SettingsB>(SettingsB settings)
{
    return std::make_shared<ConcreteDrawerB>(); //use settings here
}


void main()
{

   SettingsA setA;
   std::shared_ptr<IDrawer> pA = MakeDrawer(setA);

   SettingsB setB;
   std::shared_ptr<IDrawer> pB = MakeDrawer(setB);
}
```

You could use overloads instead of templates.

Comment: I wanted to avoid creating many overloads in  `DrawerFactory`. This looks like just moving the overloads out to template functions instead?

Comment: your example has different behaviour for the different settings types (e.g. different hard coded numbers). Those differences have to go somewhere. They'd go where I comment about using the settings. What this does do is solve the calling issue that you describe.